# How can I get notifications from the 'Updates' tab in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

Currently I only get notifications from the 'Primary' tab. Is it possible to get notifications from the 'Updates' tab as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Gmail:

Go to settings->[your Gmail address]->Manage labels

There you can tell Gmail which labels to sync and activate notifications for the label.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

Go to settings->[your Gmail address]-> Manage labels

And click `show` under `show in message list` for the category you want notifications for

[image]